# Terminology for allowing patches/modifications to a C# game

Tags: c#, patch

I need to be able to allow mods/patches to a very simple game. Essentially I need to allow a folder full of DLL files to be loaded and have their functions override those of the original application.

I know the basics of a hook system where a line of code can be placed throughout the application source to "bring in" code from outside variables and the likes.

I have tried to search for this, however as I am not sure of the terminology I have ended up sifting through about 30 sites and coming back to gaming websites with instructions on how to specifically mods their games. This information was helpful but I need a little assistance

My question is: Is there an common term for what I am trying to achieve that will assist me in google searches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably look for .NET [plug-in](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&qscrl=1&q=.net+plugin+framework&aq=4&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=.NET+plu&gs_rfai=)/[add-in](http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=1&oq=.net+addin&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+addin+framework&qscrl=1) framework. .NET Fx since 3.5 contains its own add-in framework but that may be overkill for your requirement. As such what you want to achieve is quite simple in .NET - here's the broad outline of it:

1. Define various interfaces (hooks) that need to be implemented by third party. Package them in a separate dll with documentation.
2. Create a configuration item (a config entry) that will accept the fully qualified type name implementing the requisite interface.
3. In your program, load the type using the above config entry. You can use reflection for that (see [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)). Cast the object to interface and use it.
4. Third party is supposed to provide implementation of these interfaces and place the dll under application folder. And modify config entry to put the type name.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but given .NET context, MEF (Managed Extensible Framework) or `System.AddIns` could work.

Comment: +1: From the description of the problem, [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) indeed sounds like a perfect fit.